# Mapping a byte[] that can grow up to 400KB on MySql

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I have the following:

```
@Entity
public class ExamplePhoto {

...

@Column(nullable= false)
private byte[] photo;

...
}
```

I am using Hibernate and a MySql database. I tried putting a mediumblob but got a "tinyblob expected error" message. Given the fact that the photo could be of up to 400KB the tinyblob won't do the job. How can I map this field? Is this the most elegant way of handling images?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You generally shouldn't put image blobs inside the database. Instead, put a path to the image in the database and retrieve the image from file.

Comment: MySQL handles blobs very poor. It need up to three times the memory of the byte array for reading/writing the value. For handling large blob data, consider not using a database or a blob handling one with streaming functionality like postgresql.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I know the fact that putting a path to the database could be a better option for many situations but I need to keep the pictures in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to add the `@Lob` annotation to the photo field?

```
@Column(nullable=false)
@Lob
private byte[] photo;
```

And to answer your second part, whether it is elegant to handle images that way: Depends on how frequently you are serving them. Database access is usually more expensive than plain file access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it but with the @Lob annotation it expects a "longblob", not a medium blob

Comment: What about `@Column(nullable=false, columnDefinition="mediumblob")`?

Answer (score 0):

> Given the fact that the photo could be of up to 400KB the tinyblob won't do the job. How can I map this field?

IIRC, Hibernate also uses the `length` attribute of the `Column` annotation when mapping a property as `Lob`. Try the following:

```
@Lob @Column(nullable= false, length=400000)
private byte[] photo;
```

> Is this the most elegant way of handling images?

As others have stated, the (better) alternative would be to store them on the file system and to write the path in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I know the fact that putting a path to the database could be a better option for many situations but I need to keep the pictures in the database. My question was more into whether i should use a Blob or something like that instead of byte[].